# Can't add elements to Play session

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am trying to add a simple string to a play session, but it is just not working. For testing I wrote a little controller function that first adds a string to the session and afterwards, it prints all elements the session contains, but it's always empty.

```
def foo = Action { request =>
  request.session + ("token", "foobar")
  request.session.data.foreach{ keyVal => println("\tkey value pair: " + keyVal._1 + ", " + keyVal._2)}
  Ok("just a test")
}
```

What did I do wrong? Do I need to activate something via application.conf or something else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, a session is an immutable structure as well.

It's true that the `session` object that is stored in the `request` one has a `+` method, this latter is respecting the immutability paradigm by returning a new instance of `Session`. Keeping the `request.session` unchanged.

Thinking a step further, we can assert on the fact that an updated session has only a sense when reused in another request-response transaction...

So the way to update a session is to update it while building the response (`Result` in Play), like that:

```
Ok("just a test").withSession(request.session + ("token", "foobar"))
```

This will add the new session field in your cookie, that will be available in the next transaction (i.e. request-response).

Comment: No problem! SO exists for that! And I know that those stuffs are no easy to grasp at first... I'll probably put a specific attention to this in my book.

Comment: @andypetrella, how to add a list of fields (elements) to the session? Thanks.

Comment: @Way just use `++` with a list

Comment: @andypetrella the compiler complains that `value ++ is not a member of play.api.mvc.Session`

Comment: damned... u'r right. ```session.copy(data = session.data ++ Seq(...))``` will do the trick